# django - How to check choices of an object and display corresponding item on html

Tags: python, django

I am working on a photo app, which allows one to upload images. From there, there are choice options for each photo -- either "PUBLIC" or "PRIVATE"--. For images that are "PUBLIC", the image will be shown on the home page without need for user authorisation. However, I am finding difficulty in filtering the images based on the choices and display the relevant object on the home page.

I am new to coding and Django, would appreciate some advice here. Thanks in advance!

This is my models.py file:

```py
class Images(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

    PRIVATE ='PR'
    PUBLIC = 'PU'

    PUBLISH_CHOICES = [
            (PRIVATE, 'Private'),
            (PUBLIC, 'Public'),]
    publish = models.CharField(max_length=7,
                        choices=PUBLISH_CHOICES,
                        default=PRIVATE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

This is my views.py file

```
class HomePageView(ListView):
    model = Images
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def my_view(request):
        myimages = Images.objects.all()
        for entry in myimages:
            publish_status = entry.get_publish_display()
        return publish_status
```

This is my index.html file:

```
{% for images in images_list %}
  {% if publish_status == Public %}
    <div class="container">
      <h3>{{images.title}}</h3>
      <img src="{{images.image.url}}" alt=" {{images.title}}">
    </div>  
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generic `ListView` returns a list of all `Images`, you can the pass them to the template - as you rightfully did - and then filter by `publish` field could be `PU` for `Public` or `PR` for `Private`.

`views.py` becomes:

```
class HomePageView(ListView):
    model = Images
    template_name = 'index.html'
```

`index.html` becomes:

```
{% for images in images_list %}
  {% if images.publish == 'PU' %}
    <div class="container">
      <h3>{{images.title}}</h3>
        <h2>{{ images.image.url }}</h2>
      <img src="{{ images.image.url }}" alt="{{images.title}}">
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Cheers.

Comment: @LishanHo I'm glad it worked for you. Could you please accept my answer as the correct one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all images, pass them to template and then filter based on publish_status. Below is how it might look like.

views.py:

```
class HomePageView(ListView):
    model = Images
    template_name = 'index.html'
```

index.html:

```
{% for image in object_list %}
  {% if image.publish_status == 'Public' %}
    <div class="container">
      <h3>{{images.title}}</h3>
      <img src="{{images.image.url}}" alt=" {{images.title}}">
    </div>  
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for image in object_list %}
  {% if image.publish_status == 'Public' %}
    <div class="container">
      <h3>{{images.title}}</h3>
      <img src="{{images.image.url}}" alt=" {{images.title}}">
    </div>  
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Try this. Edit your index.html file